# How to write square meter symbol in FPDF?

Tags: php, unicode, fpdf

I need to output square meter symbol in FPDF.
The font is `Shift JIS`.

```
//... rest omitted

$this->SetFont('SJIS');
$this->label_cell[] = '合計m²数';

//... rest omitted
```

But the rendered is result is `合計m?数`. I believe `²` is a unicode character(U+00B2). But why is it garbled? How do I render square meter symbol correctly?

Comment: All characters are Unicode characters. That's the whole point of Unicode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used `㎡` symbol instead. It worked.
`㎡` is a single symbol `U+33A1` but `m²` is letter m with superscript 2.
If you're interested in rendering superscripts in FPDF please refer to this [link](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script61.php).